# Matching View for ViewModel not found

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I have a MainView and a ViewModel which displays the current ViewModel in the middle.
I'm switching the current ViewModel between different ViewModels, the code for the switching should normally just work like this: `CurrentViewModel = new FooViewModel();` and then it should find the matching View to the ViewModel.
But when I debug the application, it just shows the path where the current viewmodel is located --> it
doesn't find the View for the ViewModel.

[image]

I used the correct file system of Caliburn.

All Views named with "View" in the end and are located in the folder "Views".
All ViewModels named with "ViewModel" in the end and are located in the folder "ViewModels"

Does anyone has an idea why it doesn't find the correct View or did I miss something?

Comment: you need to define data templates for the view

Comment: i thought that i dont have to define data templates while using caliburn micro?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define DataTemplate in your MainWindow :

```
<Window.Resources>
     <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PaymentViewModel}">
         <v:NewPaymentView/>
     </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MainMenuViewModel}">
        <v:MainMenu/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>    

 xmlns:vm ="clr-namespace:Your ViewModels"
 xmlns:v="clr-namespace:Your Views"
```

Then you bind your CurrentViewModel in a Content control :

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"  />
```

Then don't forget to Raise PropertyChanged in your MainViewModel (if you are not in ctor).
It was my first post, hope this help.

Answer (score -2):

**This is for Without using any mvvm framework**

Define Data Templates for child viewmodels in Main window viewmodel.

For entire application u have to create static object for your main view model.

Then only views will be changed.

It should be like this...

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel;

    public App()
    {
        mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```